# How to stop bots from posting and causing exceptions

Tags: .net, exception, spam, bots

I have a form where anyone can fill in a review about something and this form is not inside a login area.

I started to use captcha after more and more bots was trying to input spam.
The problem now is that some sort of bot just isn't giving up. I receive loads of exception emails everyday since the bot tries to input "dangerous" data and .NET doesn't allow this because the request is validated. 
The captcha doesn't help at all since it doesn't even need to be filled in to try to make a post which will cause an exception. The bot doesn't seem to understand that it fails everytime.

Yesterday I tried changing the names of the text boxes and I also added a "honeypot". But it's the same problem as with captcha, the exception occurs before anything is actually posted to the code behind.

Should I really have to set ValidateRequest="false" to enable the bot to make it a step further and maybe stop making requests?

All ideas are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- Set ValidateRequest="false" on the page, opening up the possibility of XSS.
- Override the Page_Error() and then capture the exception and deal with it in your own way.

I think you might have to combine the 2 to get this to work.

```
protected void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Exception oops = Server.GetLastError();

  if(oops.GetBaseException() is System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException) 
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: But would this stop the bot really? Do you mean if I catch the exception and don't do anything with it, the bot might believe it posted successfully or that it finally understands that it failed?

Comment: If the issue is that you don't want exceptions with invalid form data to reach the event log, then you're going to have to catch those exceptions - nevermind what the users (bots) see.

Comment: But they will keep trying to post data, using up band width.. Maybe this is the best solution, but it should be a better way. Btw, i can't deny by IP address since they are totally random.

Comment: @Andreas At a fundamental level you cannot prevent a bot from sending an HTTP `POST` to any of your URLs. There might be trickery involved using javascript, where maybe the submit cannot proceed until client-side script sets the submit url (and hopefully bots don't run your javascript). But at a fundamental level you cannot stop a TCP packet that contains `POST /SubmitReview.aspx HTTP/1.1 ...`

Comment: True.. I actually tried disabling the button and enabling it with javascript but the bot doesn't need the button :) I will settle with this solution for now. Thank you Ian and Dominic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the bot is quite stupid. Instead of having that form box in html encrypt it with javascript. It is possible that this will confuse the bot sufficiently.